# Need to show list of objects in lightning-datatable

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

**I have a requirement where I need to show list of all objects in a lightning datatable. I have fetched the list but datatable does not display the list. Below is my code, please suggest how to do it?**

*.controller*

```java
public with sharing class MangoMapController {
   
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<String> getObjects(){
        List<string> sObjectList = new List<string>();
        for(Schema.SObjectType objTyp : Schema.getGlobalDescribe().Values()){
            String name = objTyp.getDescribe().getName();
            if((name != 'Map_Objects__c')){
                SobjectList.add(name);
            }
        }
        return sObjectList;
    }
}
```

*.html*

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
    <lightning-tabset>
        <lightning-tab label="Select Object">
            <lightning-datatable class="slds-border_top" key-field="id" data={objectOptions} columns={columns}
                        onrowaction={handleRowAction}>
                    </lightning-datatable>
    </lightning-tabset>
</lightning-card>
</template>
```

*.js*

```js
import { LightningElement,track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getObjects from '@salesforce/apex/MangoMapController.getObjects';
export default class MangoMapComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track objectOptions = [];

    @wire(getObjects)
    Objects(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.objectOptions = [];
            console.log(result.data);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                var item = {
                    label: result.data[i],
                    value: result.data[i]
                };
                this.objectOptions.push(item)

        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }

    @track columns = [{
        label: 'Object Label',
        fieldName: this.objectOptions,
        type: 'text'
    }
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do below changes and try it:

```
import { LightningElement,track, wire } from 'lwc';

import getObjects from '@salesforce/apex/MangoMapController.getObjects';

export default class MangoMapComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track objectOptions = [];

    @wire(getObjects)
    Objects(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.objectOptions = [];
            console.log(result.data);
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                /* Add id and a property which will contain object name. */
                var item = {
                    id: i,
                    objectName: result.data[i],
                };
                this.objectOptions.push(item)
            }
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = undefined;
        }
    }

    @track columns = [{
        label: 'Object Label',
        /* Here we need to pass the item object's property name which contain value of Object Name Which is objectName in this case.  */
        fieldName: 'objectName',
        type: 'text'
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked

Answer (score 0):

The fieldName needs to match what you named the field, in this case, `label`. You can also optimize your code heavily with the Array.map function.

```
import { LightningElement, wire } from 'lwc';

import getObjects from '@salesforce/apex/MangoMapController.getObjects';
export default class MangoMapComponent extends LightningElement {
    @track objectOptions = [];
    columns = [{ label: 'Object Label', fieldName: 'label' }];
    @wire(getObjects)
    Objects(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            this.objectOptions = result.data.map(value => ({ label: value, value }));
            this.error = null;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
            this.data = null;
        }
    }
}
```